# How to store the results of "Find /C" as a variable

Tags: variables, batch-file, find

I'm writing a simple batch file where I'm using the `find /C` command and want to set the result of that to be a value for a variable.

More generally, is there a way to get the previous lines result to store as a variable? I will provide an example to explain what I mean here as there is some confusion.

EX1. Find /C "abcd" text.txt

This outputs a number, this number is what I mean by "previous line's result."

EX2. time /T

This outputs the current system time, the time is what I mean by "previous line's result."

Comment: So you just mean "the result of the command" then?

Comment: Yes, the "result of the command" or "command output." Is there a general script that will work to assign that to a variable or can variables only be assigned to integer values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the output of any command by using a `for` loop with the `/F` option.

```
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('command') do set your_variable=%%A
```

Note the single quotes (`'`) surrounding the command; this tells batch that it's a command and not a string or a file.

Comment: @lifesign - by default, batch splits up whatever it's processing by whitespace (spaces, tabs, and newlines). `"delims="` tells batch to not split anything up so that it all goes into the same variable. (`tokens=*` does the same thing.)

Comment: @SomethingDark, `tokens=*` removes leading (default) delimiters, where `delims=` doesn't remove anything...